# MS Chart to MS Excel

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am trying to export my MS chart from my Windows from exported out to Excel. Are there any ways to go about doing it or any website that I should look into for help? I have searched with Google but it only shows ASP .NET which is not applicable to me.

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29rbC.jpg)

[What I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCbbf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of chart, Try to export the values or data of chart in Excel (table(s)) and create the chart in the excel so it can be auto populated in there.

Comment: what if i am able to convert my chart to an image file can i insert into excel?

Comment: Yes you can. But with that, you have to convert every time you want to update your excel sheet. But with data, All you have to do is to copy and paste it in an Excel table.